# Selector UIView.endEditing crashing with UIBarButtonItem but it's working with UITapGestureRecognizer Swift 5

Tags: swift, uiview, selector, swift5, uibarbuttonitem

I want to dismiss keyboard when click on done button of UIBarButtonItem and I Don't want to add selector function @objc method.

> #selector(UIView.endEditing) - This selector is working fine with **UITapGestureRecognizer**

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action:#selector(UIView.endEditing))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

> Doing same thing with UIBarButtonItem - It **Crashing**

```
let done = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
```

I am adding this done button to ToolBar adding reference code here

```
let toolBar = UIToolbar()
toolBar.sizeToFit()

let done = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
let spacebar = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
toolBar.setItems([spacebar ,done], animated: false)
firstnameField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

Crash Image:
[image]

All things are working fine but when I tap on Done button it will crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because you are setting the target to `self` in the `UIBarButtonItem` scenario.

It should not be `self` because your class is not handling this event and that's why it crashes.

Make the target the view like you did in the gesture:

```
let done = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done,
                                   target: view, // Not self
                                   action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
```

I think this should solve it